# Snowflake sending messages to Google Pub/Sub

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm interested in using Snowflake to send a JSON object to a Google pub/sub.

I'm struggling to find good documentation on how to do this.
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Automating-Your-Snowflake-Database-Cloning-with-GCP

Is this possible within Snowflake, or will this have to be done with something like Python?

Comment: I know we use pub/sub for [Snowpipe](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-gcs.html#automating-snowpipe-for-google-cloud-storage) not sure if it can be used for general purposes.

Comment: I have their JSON creds, with the project id, client id, auth token and so on...

They have a Python script going something like "from google.cloud import pubsub_v1 ...future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data)"

Comment: Snowflake can't script anything that exists outside the Snowflake environment. You could copy the json data out to an external stage where it could be subsequently processed or you could call an external function from within Snowflake - but I can't think of any solution that wont require additional scripts written/running outside of Snowflake